# how to use a user-define function (UDF) to encrypt a column data

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to encrypt a column (studentID) in SQL Server 2008R2 using a UDF (and I will call it in a View). For example, studentID 1234567 is converted to ABCDEF (characters only). Can you show me how to do that? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This may help you you http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/string-encryption.aspx

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks! I will check the codes out.

Comment: @marc_s: I checked it out, it's simple and interesting. I'd like to encrypt from 7 digit (varchar type) to 7 character only. That example will convert the input string to some un-readable character. How can I modify it, so it will encrypts the studentId to characters only? Thanks